Series that involves permutation in the denominator
Hi I have another factorial series exercise and I don't know how to solve it
$$\sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{1}{(k-2)!(k^2-1)}$$
for $ m \geq 2$
and if I subtitute I get :
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{30}+....+\frac{1}{(n-2)!*(n^{2}-1)}$$
And from here ????

This is the same as the series from your last question, except it begins a term later.

As Theo rightly points out in the comments, it's almost the same as your previous series. You just do $$\frac1{(k-2)!(k^2-1)}=\frac1{(k-2)!(k-1)(k+1)}=\frac{k}{(k+1)k(k-1)(k-2)!}=\frac{k}{(k+1)!}$$ Now sum it by telescoping.
